# MissingMethodException in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I was facing the MissingMethodExeption while using the reflection method in Xamarin.iOS. My code works fine when Linker Behavior is set to Don't Link. But i am getting the above exception when Linker behavior is set to Link SDK assemblies. I have tried the workaround to set the --linkskip=System.Core but exception raised. Can you please let me know if you have any answer for this problem.

I am getting the error while performing the following operation. Activator.CreateInstance(resultType) as ScriptObject. Here resultType is a Type and ScriptObject is a class which perform some operations for me.

Comment: Can you add the code which throws the exception?

Comment: @DennisSchröer, I am getting the error while performing the following operation. Activator.CreateInstance(resultType) as ScriptObject. Here resultType is a Type and ScriptObject is a class which perform some operations for me.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to avoid some methods/types to be linked out is to reference them in unused code:

```cs
if (false) {
    var a = new TypeToPreserve();
    a.MethodToPreserve();
}
```